# What language should I use?

Tags: php

I need to make two table, 1. *Offered course* and 2. *Taken Course*. *Offered course* table will have rows from database. There will be option to take course from *offered course* table ans remove course from *taken course* table. Course taken from *offered course* will be shown in taken course and vice-versa.

I want to build this in PHP. But I am new to php and I don't know if I can do it using only php or not.

Help me suggesting language and a reference will be so much helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Unless you want to have to submit the page to the server every time a course is added or deleted, you would do this using Javascript in the page itself.

Comment: If you're new to PHP, read some tutorials and give it a shot. This question is  off topic since suggestions about which language will be 100% opinion based (and there for off topic) and asking for "references" is asking for off-site resources (which also is off topic).

Comment: php is server side, meaning that you php process your input and output data then sends it to your client side, we don't know what your application will be doing or what is it purpose so its hard to recommend a client side code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one **non**-opinion-based piece of advice we can give you is that if you want this to be nice and interactive and quick, you'll want to handle most of this logic on the client browser. *That* means one of two things:

1. Using JavaScript or a language that compiles to JavaScript like TypeScript, CoffeeScript, or Dart (I think those are the big three), since JavaScript is the only language browsers universally run. (Oh, or the Google Web Toolkit, where you write your application — both the client-side and server-side — in Java [not JavaScript], and it generates the JavaScript for you based on your Java code.)
2. Using any language that can be compiled to [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org) ("Wasm"). Wasm 1.0 is supported by Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Safari.

You'll still probably have a server piece. The language/environment you use for that is entirely up to you and is a complex decision. One of the things driving that decision will be where and how you want to host it. PHP is certainly one choice. If you wanted to write the client-side and server-side in the same language, [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) + [Express](http://expressjs.com) (or [Koa](http://koajs.com)) makes it straightforward to write server-side code in JavaScript (or a language that compiles to JavaScript). But you have many, many other options — the .Net ecosystem (C#, VB, F#, ...), Java, Ruby, Python...

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think PHP can do the job.
You should bind it with a database. If you know a bit OOP (Object Oriented Programming) you can use the PHP extension PDO (PHP Data Objects ) for persistence. As reference you can take a look at the MySql [workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/) and the official documentation of PDO.
Happy coding !